# How to get/add GCS File user-defined metadata using Apache Beam library [org.apache.beam.sdk.io.*]

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io, spotify-scio

I'm setting up a Dataflow pipeline, in which one of the action is to get/add the metadata[User-provided metadata] of a GCS file.

In a standalone java app I used below method to get the metadata which is from StorageObject class but not finding something similar method/api in Apache Beam library. Any pointers will be really helpful.

```
//Below code is from StorageObject.java
com.google.api.services.storage.model.StorageObject
//.....
public java.util.Map<String, java.lang.String> getMetadata() {
     return metadata;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to make use of the client library directly within a DoFn as user code?

Comment: I used com.google.cloud.storage.Storage to get the metadata of a GCS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used following code to get the metadata from GCS and it works good in DataFlow pipeline.

```
import com.google.cloud.storage.{BlobId, BlobInfo, Storage, StorageOptions}

val storage: Storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance.getService
val blobId: BlobId = BlobId.of("bucket", "filename")
val srcMap: Map[String, String] = storage.get(blobId).getMetadata
```